# SUMMARY 2 data in one table

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to add left qty as A grade and left qty+right qty as C grade, how do I display the result of adding left qty+right qty? while the first left qty has been calculated as A grade

below my database table and my code

```
select sum (left_qty) as A_grade,
       sum (left_qty+right_qty) as C_grade 
from bonus_produksi 
where grade like 'A' and .......... ?
```

i try use this code

```
SELECT SUM(LEFT_QTY) AS TOTAL_A_GRADE 
FROM BONUS_PRODUKSI
WHERE GRADE LIKE 'A'
UNION
SELECT SUM(LEFT_QTY+RIGHT_QTY) AS TOTAL_C_GRADE 
FROM BONUS_PRODUKSI;
```

but the result is C grade is show on column a grade, I want to make the results of A grade and C grade side by side in 1 query or code

i want make the result side by side by 1 query

Comment: that is what UNION makes, if both sums where identical you would get only one row as result, as UNION eliminates duplicates, you are looking for conditional SUMs

Comment: if you want help writing a db query, we need to see a CREATE TABLE for the tables in question, desired result, and enough sample data to provide the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using a conditional sum:

```sql
SELECT
    SUM(IF(grade LIKE 'A', left_qty, NULL)) AS A_grade,
    SUM(left_qty + right_qty) AS C_grade 
FROM bonus_produksi
```